# Norm of $a +b\alpha + c\alpha^2 + d\alpha^3$ in $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

Is there an easy way to calculate the norm of the element $a +b\alpha + c\alpha^2 + d\alpha^3$ in $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$, where $\alpha^4 = -4\alpha^2 - 2$ and $a,b,c,d \in \mathbb{Z}$? I know that it is an integer, however I want to show that it is not divisible by $16$.

I know that it can be done using the definition of the norm as the determinant of the following matrix

$$\begin{pmatrix}
a & -2d & -2c & 8d-2b\\
b & a & -2d & -2c\\
c & -4d + b & -4c + a & 14d - 4b\\
d & c & b - 4d & a - 4c\\
\end{pmatrix},$$

but surely there is an easier way.

Comment: Well, that determinant is the norm, by definition.

Comment: Of course, but there must be an easier way to calculate that this determinant is not divisible by 16? For example, mod $2$, the determinant equals $a^4$, therefore, if $a$ is odd, it will not be divisible by 16.

Comment: See also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/165730/calculating-the-norm-of-an-element-in-a-field-extension.

Comment: I really don’t see this kind of computation as particularly difficult, as long as the degree of the extension is not too high.