(sub)monoids of the positive integers under multiplication, with density $0$ in the positive integers, are always multiplicative norms of rings?
Consider integer polynomials of type $"x"$ where we take as imput nonnegative integers.
With these nonnegative integer imputs we strictly generate a subset of nonnegative integers ; the set $X$.
The set $X$ needs to contain the number $1$.
Now we want that these integer polynomials are closed under multiplication.
A monoid is a set equipped with an associative binary operation and an identity element. For example, the nonnegative integers with addition form a monoid, the identity element being 0.
So we want these integer polynomials to be monoids under multiplication.
Also we want that this set $X$ has density $0$ in the positive integers.
A simple example is the sum of two squares :
the Brahmagupta–Fibonacci identity
$$(a^2  + b^2)(c^2 + d^2) = (ac - bd)^2 + (ad + bc)^2 = (ac + bd)^2 + (ad - bc)^2$$
Hence the set of all sums of two squares is closed under multiplication and we have our monoid.
I want to point out that I am only considering upto isomorphism , that is to say :
$$a^4 + b^4$$
$$(a^2  + b^2)(c^2 + d^2)$$
$$(a^2  + b^2 +c^2 + d^2)^2 + (x^2 + y^2 + z^2 + w^2)^2$$
are considered the same as " $a^2 + b^2$ ". They are of the same type.
They are just subsets , compositions , products , representations ( every positive integer is the sum of 4 squares ! )
A more general example is the product of two numbers of the form
${\displaystyle a^{2}+nb^{2}}$ is itself a number of that form.
The norm of the Eisenstein integers is another example.
Finally I make the conjecture :
considering upto isomorphism,
The integer polynomial (sub)monoids of the positive integers under multiplication, with density $0$ in the positive integers, are always multiplicative norms of rings or products of such.
I would like a proof or disproof or counterexample.
Edit :
$$ f(a,b,c) = a^3+2 b^3-6 a b c+4 c^3 = \left|\begin{bmatrix} a & 2c & 2b\\b & a & 2c\\ c & b & a\end{bmatrix}\right|,  $$
Seems like a solution but I think the matrix is a representation of a ring, so almost but not quite ?
Which brings me to another remark, matrices and rings tend to have negative terms in their norms or determinants.
So positive polynomials might be of special interest.
+1 if you can give me the ring this matrix is a representation of.
Also :
similar or related :
On the cubic generalization $(a^3+b^3+c^3+d^3)(e^3+f^3+g^3+h^3 ) = v_1^3+v_2^3+v_3^3+v_4^3$ for the Euler four-square
where they consider sum of cubes being multiplied.
Similar thing :
Is there a generalization of Brahmagupta–Fibonacci identity for cubic?

NOT THE MAIN QUESTION !
Bonus question : does closed under product imply closed under division whenever division is possible ?
+1 if you can answer this.
Might add it as a new question (edit and split up)


See also : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2469516/is-there-a-generalization-of-brahmagupta-fibonacci-identity-for-cubic

your matrix ring  comes from a matrix $W$  and all  combinations $aI + b W + c W^2$  The product of two such elements is another, Cayley-Hamilton for $W$ is involved, giving expressions for $W^3, W^4, W^5$  as needed. Determinants also multiply.

Homework: two by two $$ W = \left(
\begin{array}{rr}
0 & -1 \
n & 0 \
\end{array}
\right)
$$
What is determinant of $aI + b W ;  ; ? ; ; $  Note $W^2 = -nI.$   Then, find the coefficients $e,f$ in $$  (aI+bW)(cI+dW)  = eI + fW$$

Your $f(a,b,c)$ is the norm of $a+b\root3\of2+c\root3\of4$, see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/165730/calculating-the-norm-of-an-element-in-a-field-extension
